# Is there a way to convert the Slider to a non-linear scale for Windows 8?

Tags: windows, user-interface, microsoft-metro

Alternatively Is there a way i can convert the existing one to behave like a non-linear ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a Value converter that turns the linear value into a non-linear value.

This way you would not make the Slider non-linear but it would be functional.

If you really need the Slider to be non-linear you could subclass it and modify its behavior.

Comment: But the tag which shows the value while dragging the slider will be wrong. Any way to tackle that.

Comment: Just remove the tag or change it in the ControlTemplate to use the same value converter.